# Запрос с условием в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, условия

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить SQL запрос, если такое вообще возможно.
Есть таблица с документами в которых указан номер документа, товар, его количество и вес
Нужно посчитать средний вес определенного товара из всех документов, а затем сравнить его со средним весом товара по каждому документу, и, в случае несовпадения, вывести номера этих документов.

Сейчас я на следующем этапе:

```
SELECT товар, SUM(вес товара)/SUM(кол-во товара)  AS СреднийВес 
FROM таблица1, таблица2 [в одной таблице есть данные по весу, во второй по количеству]
WHERE (таблица1.товар = таблица2.товар) 
GROUP BY товар [на данном этапе я получила средний вес товара в каждом документе]
```

Как мне дальше сравнить его с общим средним весом товара из всех документов и вывести номера документов, где средние веса будут отличаться?
Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Comment: *Как мне дальше сравнить его с общим средним весом товара из всех документов* Получить в отдельном подзапросе? который будет ещё одним источником данных. И не используйте картезианское произведение, перепишите на JOIN.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш комментарий! В отдельном запросе? Или в этом же? Если в отдельном, то как мне связать два вместе два запроса? А чем плохо картезианское произведение?

Comment: *В отдельном запросе? Или в этом же?* В подзапросе. *чем плохо картезианское произведение?* Непрозрачность. Смешиваются условия связывания и отбора, сложно перейти на внешнее связывание, если потребуется.